# Debug Keystone in Myeclipse raised Exception

Tags: openstack, keystone

i followd this page  [Setup keystone in Eclipse](https://wiki.openstack.org/w/index.php?title=Setup_keystone_in_Eclipse&oldid=18278) , and debug the keystone branch of stable/folsom ， after i launch the debug menu, the console wirite this:

---

```
pydev debugger: starting
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/hub.py", line 336, in fire_timers timer()

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/hubs/timer.py", line 56, in __call__
    cb(*args, **kw)

   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/semaphore.py", line 95, in _acquire  waiter.switch()

error: cannot switch to a different thread
```

---

Because of this i can not debug with it. However it works well when i start i without debug mode.
I ‘m really appreciate if anyone can give me some advices on how to debug keystone source code using any ide or anything else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below mentioned link. In that, at one point, he has mentioned how to set the environment variable on eclipse to use standard_threading. I tried that and it worked. Hoping it would also work for you.

http://adam.younglogic.com/2012/12/keystone-and-eclipse-pydev/

Thanks.